# How I can find instagram user id and show feed?

Tags: php, json, instagram

I need to show users instagram feed. How I can do it?

I tried to use

```
<?php
    function insta_api( $api_url ){
        $connection_c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
        $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c );
        curl_close( $connection_c );
        return json_decode( $json_return );
    }
    $access_token = '...access.token.here...';
    $user_search = insta_api( 'https://instagram.com/' . $instagram_login . '/?__a=1' );
    print_r($user_search);
    $user_id = $user_search['id'];
    echo $user_id;
    $return = insta_api('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $user_id . '/media/recent?access_token=' . $access_token);
```

?

But it returns

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id

Also I tried to use

```
https://www.instagram.com/user_name/?__a=1
```

But I can't get json value, and I think it's not good practice.

Thanks

Comment: So, output of `$user_search` you expect us to guess?

Comment: Now it doesn't return nothing. But I want to return json object, which you can see if go https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1  and then get user ID

Comment: I don't see value of `$instagram_login`. Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's correct, i send this value from admin dashboard and it's works

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use this endpoint:
`https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/media/`

No auth needed and you have access to the 20 latest posts.